# Can a Makefile 'include' be dynamically set based on the target?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Let's say I have two files.
File profile/A.mk:

```
NAME=A
VERSION=1.0
```

File profile/B.mk:

```
NAME=A
VERSION=2.0
```

The Makefile might look like:

```
BASE_DIR:=$(shell sh -c 'pwd')
include $(BASE_DIR)/profile/<**NOT_SURE_WHAT_TO_PUT_HERE**>.mk

A B:
    @echo $(VERSION)
```

I guess what I want is to be able "source" or "include" only the *.mk file based upon the make command:

```
make A
```

or

```
make B
```

Because I use NAME and VERSION in both *.mk files, I can't do an "include" of both *.mk files. An include of both files generates an "overwriting previous assignment" warning.

In a shell script, the **NOT_SURE_WHAT_TO_PUT_HERE** would be **$1**. Is there a variable/macro/something where I use the target name to include *.mk based on the target name? 
(GNU Make 3.81, Ubuntu 13.04)

Comment: There's no reason to manually invoke a shell to run `pwd. `$(shell pwd)` will work. That being said neither of those is necessary because GNU make at least has both `$PWD` and [`$CURDIR`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bCURDIR_007d-389) available by default.

Comment: Note that `$(PWD)` is not set by make; it's inherited from the parent's environment.  If the caller of make doesn't set that variable then it won't be available.  You should use `$(CURDIR)` which is set by make and so will always be available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the variable [`$(MAKECMDGOALS)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Goals.html).

Comment: Use `$(word 1,$(MAKECMDGOALS))` or `$(firstword $(MAKECMDGOALS))` to work like shell `$1`.